# Ember setting a property from a reopened class

Tags: ember.js

I have used `.reopen` in my file to do a few changes to a class, but I'm struggling to change a computed property in the same file.

I'll start with a simple property.  This is all within my **custom-date-picker.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    ...
    outputRange: "test",
    ...
});

powerCalendarRange.reopen({
    actions: {
        select(day, calendar, e) {
          let range = this._buildRange(day);
          let { start, end } = range.moment;
          this.set('outputRange', "set");
          if (start && end) {
            let { minRange, maxRange } = this.get('publicAPI');
            let diff = Math.abs(end.diff(start));
            if (diff < minRange.as('ms') || maxRange && diff > maxRange.as('ms')) {
              return;
            }
          }
          let action = this.get('onSelect');
          if (action) {
            action(range, calendar, e);
          }
        }
    }
});
```

then of course, I'd like to show `outputRange` in an html element like so:

```
<input type="text" value="{{outputRange}}" />
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, and I think it has to do with `this`.  What should I be looking into?

Comment: what is your component name in which you defined  `outputRange` ? . Are you passing `outputRange` to the `powerCalendarRange` component ?. what is that `powerCalendarRange` ?

Comment: @kumkanillam, The script I'm showing is a `custom-date-picker.js` part of my component.  the `powerCalendarRange` is an import of an NPM module of `ember-power-calendar`.  I did not pass the `outputRange` to the `powerCalendarRange`.  I wasn't aware I needed to.  Do I need to pass the value TO the reopened class and then get it back?

Comment: So where are you trying to show `outputRange` ? is that in your `custom-date-picker.js`. if its so then you need to pass `outputRange` to `powerCalendarRange` component.

Answer (score 0):

`custom-date-picker` is your component, and `power-calendar-range` is different component, Components are isolated, you need to pass `outputRange` property from `custom-date-picker` to  `power-calendar-range`.

Why do you want to reOpen?. I believe you can solve your use case without `reOpen` but by extending `power-calendar-range` component.

Comment: Sorry this may not fix your problem

Comment: yeah, sry it does not.  the value isn't being passed properly on change